# after typing stty raw -echo the terminal stuck and doesn't work?

Tags: command-line, bash

Not much to explain, I am basically practising some penetration testings, so I have spawned a low privilege shell, which is connected through `nc`. but now to get a properly working shell, as everyone says, I could do CTRL+Z > type `stty raw -echo` > fg, but when I do so, my terminal get stuck and when I type I just see my keyboard pointer blinking but doesn't type anything, I don't even know how to kill the terminal which is stuck in tmux.

prior to running `stty raw -echo` when I do `ls -l /bin/bash` I see:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  7 Jan  4  2014 /bin/bash -> /bin/sh
```

Comment: Read `man stty`or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/stty.1.html

Comment: "as everyone says" – who and where says to issue that `stty` command? What is it supposed to fix?